# Why does my Python XML parser break after the first file?

Tags: python, for-loop, xml-parsing

I am working on a Python (3) XML parser that should extract the text content of specific nodes from every xml file within a folder. Then, the script should write the collected data into a tab-separated text file. So far, all the functions seem to be working. The script returns all the information that I want from the first file, but it always breaks, I believe, when it starts to parse the second file.

When it breaks, it returns "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable." I've checked the second file and found that the functions work just as well on that as the first file when I remove the first file from the folder. I'm very new to Python/XML. Any advice, help, or useful links would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import glob
import csv
import sys

content_file = open('WWP Project/WWP_texts.txt','wt')
quotes_file = open('WWP Project/WWP_quotes.txt', 'wt')
list_of_files = glob.glob("../../../Documents/WWPtextbase/distribution/*.xml")

ns = {'wwp':'http://www.wwp.northeastern.edu/ns/textbase'}

def content(tree):
    lines = ''.join(ET.tostring(tree.getroot(),encoding='unicode',method='text')).replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ').strip()
    clean_lines = re.sub(' +',' ', lines)
    return clean_lines.lower()

def quotes(tree):
    quotes_list = []
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:quote', namespaces=ns):
        quote = ET.tostring(node,encoding='unicode',method='text')
        clean_quote = re.sub(' +',' ', quote)
        quotes_list.append(clean_quote)
    return ' '.join(str(v) for v in quotes_list).replace('\t','').replace('\n','').lower()

def pid(tree):
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:sourceDesc//wwp:author/wwp:persName[1]', namespaces=ns):
        pid = node.attrib.get('ref')
    return pid.replace('personography.xml#','') # will need to replace 'p:'


def trid(tree): # this function will eventually need to call OT (.//wwp:publicationStmt//wwp:idno)
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:sourceDesc',namespaces=ns):
        trid = node.attrib.get('n')
    return trid

content_file.write('pid' + '\t' + 'trid' + '\t' +'text' + '\n')
quotes_file.write('pid' + '\t' + 'trid' + '\t' + 'quotes' + '\n')

for file_name in list_of_files:
    file = open(file_name, 'rt')
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    file.close()
    pid = pid(tree)
    trid = trid(tree)
    content = content(tree)
    quotes = quotes(tree)
    content_file.write(pid + '\t' + trid + '\t' + content + '\n')
    quotes_file.write(pid + '\t' + trid + '\t' + quotes + '\n')

content_file.close()
quotes_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your function calls with the values they returned.  changing the function names should fix it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import glob
import csv
import sys

content_file = open('WWP Project/WWP_texts.txt','wt')
quotes_file = open('WWP Project/WWP_quotes.txt', 'wt')
list_of_files = glob.glob("../../../Documents/WWPtextbase/distribution/*.xml")

ns = {'wwp':'http://www.wwp.northeastern.edu/ns/textbase'}

def get_content(tree):
    lines = ''.join(ET.tostring(tree.getroot(),encoding='unicode',method='text')).replace('\n',' ').replace('\t',' ').strip()
    clean_lines = re.sub(' +',' ', lines)
    return clean_lines.lower()

def get_quotes(tree):
    quotes_list = []
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:quote', namespaces=ns):
        quote = ET.tostring(node,encoding='unicode',method='text')
        clean_quote = re.sub(' +',' ', quote)
        quotes_list.append(clean_quote)
    return ' '.join(str(v) for v in quotes_list).replace('\t','').replace('\n','').lower()

def get_pid(tree):
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:sourceDesc//wwp:author/wwp:persName[1]', namespaces=ns):
        pid = node.attrib.get('ref')
    return pid.replace('personography.xml#','') # will need to replace 'p:'


def get_trid(tree): # this function will eventually need to call OT (.//wwp:publicationStmt//wwp:idno)
    for node in tree.findall('.//wwp:sourceDesc',namespaces=ns):
        trid = node.attrib.get('n')
    return trid

content_file.write('pid' + '\t' + 'trid' + '\t' +'text' + '\n')
quotes_file.write('pid' + '\t' + 'trid' + '\t' + 'quotes' + '\n')

for file_name in list_of_files:
    file = open(file_name, 'rt')
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    file.close()
    pid = get_pid(tree)
    trid = get_trid(tree)
    content = get_content(tree)
    quotes = get_quotes(tree)
    content_file.write(pid + '\t' + trid + '\t' + content + '\n')
    quotes_file.write(pid + '\t' + trid + '\t' + quotes + '\n')

content_file.close()
quotes_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, miah! That definitely got things started. It's parsing more of the files now, but not all of them. I'm now getting a `TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly`. Perhaps, one of the files doesn't conform to the rest and is breaking the script?

Comment: Without seeing any of the data, I would the return value from one of the `get_*` functions is `None`, so it is failing when trying to write to the content or quotes file.  I would have it print out the name of the files as it tries them, so that you can then go look at the file that fails.

Comment: That worked perfectly, miah. Thanks again for your help!